Wix 4 XSD files
Where can I find the schema definition XSD files for Wix 4?
Looked around a bit and I realise I can't find neither the files nor the links to them.
I'd like to use those XSD in Visual Studio Code for editing Wix installer XML files the similar way we do in Visual Studio with HeatWave (having autocompletion, etc.).
Is that possible?

Well, found the XSDs at https://github.com/wixtoolset/web/tree/master/src/xsd4
(the source of the link is in turn this message https://github.com/orgs/wixtoolset/discussions/7944#discussioncomment-8004183)
Works and is really practical:
Tooltips

"Auto-completion"

Validation

What I did is:

cloned the Wix "web" repo (https://github.com/wixtoolset/web.git) to a local directory on my laptop

created an "XML catalog" file with the content like this


<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">

  <uri
      name="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
      uri="C:\Users\dliak.DESKTOP-DMQT043\src\web\src\xsd4\wix.xsd" />

</catalog>


Added that catalog to the VSCode configuration JSON file adding this line

"xml.catalogs": ["C:\\Users\\dliak.DESKTOP-DMQT043\\catalog.xml"]

And that's it
